# Purity of Herbal Supplements

Tags: supplements

There is plenty of debate about the efficacy of most herbal supplements, but that's not my question.

I just want to know if there is a reliable/standard source of verification for the active ingredient *purity* of particular branded/packaged herbal supplements.

In other words, if I buy Brand X Gingko Biloba tablets, how much Gingko Biloba is in each tablet, and how much is inert fillers?

I have heard of organizations that audit the manufacturing sites of herbal supplement makers, including USP and NSF, but it appears that they do not actually test the contents of the supplements themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, herbal supplements aren't regulated so the short answer is no. There is no independent verification so you must trust the source or caveat emptor.